# Understanding the result of mload

Tags: solidity

```
        uint256 x = 0x12345678;
        uint8 y = uint8(x);
        console2.log(y);

        uint16 y2;
        bytes2 y3;
        assembly {
            let p := mload(0x40)
            mstore(p, x)
            y := mload(p)
            y2 := mload(p)
            y3 := mload(p)
        }
        console2.log(y);
        console2.log(y2);
        console2.log(vm.toString(y3));
```

Output：

```
Logs:
  120
  120
  22136
  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The output of `y` and `y2` is as expected(the lowest byte of `x`), but the output of `y3` is all zero, why `mload` the same slot to uint16 and bytes2 gives totally different result?

(the console2 library is from forge-std)

Answer (score 1):

`bytes2` takes the first two bytes *on the left* of the number, i.e. the most significant bytes.

Some examples:

```js
bytes2(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012345678) = 0x0000

bytes2(0xa763062200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012345678) = 0xa763
```